# База данных для группового чата

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Проектирую базу данных для группового чата. В результате появилось несколько вопросов. Ниже привожу написанные модели и вопросы к ним.

**User**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public Uri Image { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> UserFriends { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public virtual IList<GroupChat> GroupChats { get; set; } = new List<GroupChat>();
}
```

**GroupChat**

Пользователь может состоять в нескольких групповых переписках. В каждой переписке создается коллекция прочитанных и непрочитанных сообщений(*наверное подход не очень*). Сделал 2 коллекции чтобы быстрей можно было получать список всех непрочитанных сообщений. Когда приходит новое сообщение в чат то нужно хранить информацию прочитано ли это сообщение каждым из участников чата.

**1.** Подскажите, как это сделать максимально аккуратно и эффективно?

```
public class GroupChat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
    public IList<GroupMessage> GroupMessages { get; set; } = new List<GroupMessage>();
    public IList<GroupMessage> UnreadGroupMessages { get; set; } = new List<GroupMessage>();
}
```

**GroupMessage**

В групповом сообщении храню список пользователей для которых предназначено это сообщение.

**2.** Это нормально?

```
public class GroupMessage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User FromUser { get; set; }
        public IList<User> ToUsers { get; set; }
        public Message Message { get; set; }
    }
```

**Message**

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Очень хочется услышать опытные советы, чтобы понять в правильном направлении ли я движусь.

Comment: Не бывает "непрочитанного вообще" сообщения, бывает сообщение, которое не было прочитано конкретным пользователем.

Comment: Да, я это и имел в виду. Только я не понимаю как это можно реализовать.

Comment: А почему не сделать еще одну таблицу в которой будут храниться сообщения прочитанные пользователями  ( ID Message и ID User) ?

Comment: @Batanichek, В классе `GroupChat` есть два свойства : `Users` и `GroupMessages` которые я так понимаю являются аналогами ваших `user_in_group и message_in_group`.

Comment: @Batanichek, в `GroupChat` свойство `Users` это пользователи которые состоят в переписке. `ToUsers` это список пользователей которым отправляется сообщение. То есть может быть ситуация что сообщение было отправлено 5 пользователям, после этого в переписку вступил еще один. Вот для него это сообщение не должно быть видно, потому что оно для него не предназначалось и в момент отправки сообщения этого пользователя еще не было в группе.

Comment: ок .. я именно это и уточнял --будет ли видно это сообщение пользователю или нет.